# Proper way to move Django model fields to subclass causing wrong migration

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to perform what would ostensibly be a noop on my Django model. It currently looks like

```
class OrgParent(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    organization = models.ForeignKey(...)
    order = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        unique_together = (('name', 'order'),)
        ordering = ('order',)

class OrgChild(OrgParent)
    other_field = models.CharField()
```

And I want to squash it down so that it's just a single model:

```
class OrgChild(models.Model)
    other_field = models.CharField()
    name = models.CharField()
    organization = models.ForeignKey(...)
    order = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        unique_together = (('name', 'order'),)
        ordering = ('order',)
```

However when I do this Django (running 1.7, planning to upgrade soon) on `manage.py makemigrations` creates an automigration that actually deletes my whole table!

```
  xxxx_auto_xxxxxxx_xxxxx.py:
    - Alter unique_together for organizationchild (0 constraint(s))
    - Remove field organization from organizationchild
    - Delete model OrganizationChild
```

I imagine the database backing for this new model would work exactly the same way, so I don't actually need a migration. Is there a way to ignore migrations? Should I just check in the migration but delete the actions in it? Is there a preferred Django way to manage this migration?